# Как обратиться к объекту в unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Нужно при нажатии на кнопку "Main button", менять Active у кнопки "Home button" (то есть, отображать и прятать её). "Home button" - не вложена в "Main button".

Так как Unity недавно начал изучать, не могу понять как обратиться к кнопке "Home button", помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй это.

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    public class Buttons : MonoBehaviour {
       public GameObject MainButton;
       public GameObject HomeButton;
         public void HideMain(){    //скрываем кнопку Main
           MainButton.SetActive(false);
           HomeButton.SetActive(true);
          }
         public void HideHome(){   //скрываем кнопку Home
           MainButton.SetActive(true);
           HomeButton.SetActive(false);
          }

    }
```

Comment: Блин... Ну как же я сам не догадался, никак не могу привыкнуть к логике работы Unity. Я всё пытался как-то через переменную задать или через тэг подхватить. 10 часов залипания сказываются...

Спасибо, выручил!

Comment: @DmitryDAN если ответ вам был полезен, пожалуйста, отметьте его решением и нажмите треугольничек вверх ("Ответ полезен"), слева от ответа